# Firefox flash duplicate calls

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox, urlloader

In my flash i have an urlloader that is doing a GET operation with a parameter in the call(url&id=1). When i run the flash file in firefox browser(this case 17 but also 16) for some reason the browser is making two GET calls one with parameters and another not putting any value in the parameter(&id=). This does not happen for instance in chrome. Does anyone know why firefox has this? and how to prevent?

Comment: are you only seeing the 2 calls from the server side? or is there some behavior where flash is reacting to 2 responses?  if it's on the server side it may just be the favicon being requested...

Comment: i am using firebug and i see two call being made, and in the server side i receive two calls. while in chrome it only appears one call in the server side.

Comment: sorry, I can't think of anything off the top of my head... do you have an example up anywhere?